# Teffilin in the army

Tags: tefilin, army-military-war

One who is in the army and going to be on duty all day from before *olot* (dawn) until after *shekiya* (dusk), according to some poskim he can put on tefillin then without a bracha, while others rule that he shouldn't.

Chevel Nachalato 3:2 records a long discussion between Rav Yakov Epstein and Rav Avigdor Nevinsal, whether a soldier who is on duty from before Olot until after Shekiya can put on Tefillin before olot. Rav Nevinsal held he could but shouldn't recite a bracha. He is based on Igrot Moshe 1:10 and would apply it even on a mass scale.

But can he do it after shekiya?

Comment: Welcome, TwoOs. Besides what @JoelK said, I recommend you clarify what you're asking. I don't know what "How's that?" means here. Do you want to know __why__ the _pos'kim_ say what they do, or do you want know (about one side of the debate) __how he could possibly__ say what he does? (In the latter case, you should edit to indicate which position you're asking about and what's wrong with it.)

Comment: @AlaychemRememberMonica My instinct tells me that this is a camouflaged pesak-seeking question, but I might not be right.

Comment: @TwoOs I dared to edit your question, but please check the last sentence again, because it didn't make sense.

Comment: Did you read the Igrot Moshe you reference?

Comment: TwoOs please clarify if Kazi understood your question correctly

Comment: Why would you think he could do it after Shekiah?

Comment: https://twitter.com/IlliniRabbi/status/1399150531940175874